# Using |= for CLI argument parsing

Tags: c, command-line-interface, program-entry-point, argv, cmark

The CLI in [main.c](https://github.com/jgm/cmark/blob/0.19.0/src/main.c#L87-L94) of cmark uses the `|=` operator for combining on/off options when iterating over arguments. A simplified version looks like:

```
#define CMARK_OPT_DEFAULT 0
#define CMARK_OPT_SOURCEPOS 1
#define CMARK_OPT_HARDBREAKS 2
#define CMARK_OPT_NORMALIZE 4
#define CMARK_OPT_SMART 8

int options = CMARK_OPT_DEFAULT;

for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "--sourcepos") == 0) {
        options |= CMARK_OPT_SOURCEPOS;
    } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "--hardbreaks") == 0) {
        options |= CMARK_OPT_HARDBREAKS;
    } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "--smart") == 0) {
        options |= CMARK_OPT_SMART;
    } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "--normalize") == 0) {
        options |= CMARK_OPT_NORMALIZE;
    } 
    ...
}
```

What is the benefit of using `|=` and not `+=` to add up the options?

Comment: What is the result of `4 | 4` and `4 + 4`? You need to read about [Bitwise Operators](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitwise.html)

Comment: BTW, why do not use loop and keep options as array of pairs name -> mask.

Comment: Ok thanks I get it now. The benefit of `|=` is that it is idempotent if the same argument is specified twice. Otherwise `--sourcepos --sourcepos` would equal `--hardbreaks` which makes no sense.

Comment: @Jeroen: if `--sourcepos` may be specified more than once, you may reserve multiple bits for it and use `+=` for it. For example, `preempt_count` in Linux works like this (a single word with multiple counters inside).